# Multivariable integration using transformations

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $$ \iint_D (x + y)\  dx \ dy  $$ where $D$ is the trapezoidal region with vertices given by $ (0,0), (5,0), (5/2, 5/2), (5/2, -5/2) $, using the transformations $ x = 2u + 3v $ and $ y = 2u - 3v$.

I have close to no idea how to go about this problem. Could someone help me start it?

Comment: Check Example 2 in [Paul's Online Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx).

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales actually the exercise is completely solved in example 4.

Comment: @user486983 You are right! I did not scroll down that far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the Jacobian of the transformation. Take its absolute value, and that will scale the differential of area to give you the area differential in $(u,v)$ coordinates.

I believe the integrand substitution is straightforward.

Finally, to get the limits, sketch the trapezoidal region in the $xy$-plane, then determine the lines that bound it. Use the substitutions to determine what these lines transform into. This will show you the corresponding region in the $uv$-plane. Now you can determine the limits and integrate.